# Replace text in Word Document with ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, activex, replace

I want replace some string within Word Document using ActiveX and JavaScript, now I have something like this:

```
var text = Selection.Text;
Selection.Text = text.replace('somesting','somevalue');
```

But after that I loose all formaing.
If I record macros in WinWord I get this:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "somestring"
    .Replacement.Text = "somevalue"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

So, how can I rewrite the last string  with JS?

Answer (score 1):

```
Selection.Find.Execute('somestring',
                       false,
                       false,
                       false,
                       false,
                       false,
                       wdFindContinue,
                       false,
                       false,
                       'somevalue'
                       wdReplaceAll,
                       false,
                       false,
                       false,
                       false);
```

Also you should have some word constants, like:

```
var wdReplaceAll = 2;
var wdFindContinue = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well if the text is less than 256 characters. Refer to Article ID: 212543 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212543 for workaround.

Thanks,
Manju